# How do make queued pipeline wait till the current running pipeline finishes running, if using same build agent in Azure pipeline for multiple branches

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using the azure pipeline using YML for my CI process it is running for multiple branches in repo.

I want to make the next queued pipeline to wait till all the stages in my current pipeline are completed.

Comment: Why? What is your concern?

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your situation.

When you execute Multi-stages Pipeline runs, the Pipeline agent execution jumps between stages.

For example:

[image]

The Pipeline agent will not completely run all the current stages and then continue to run the next pipeline.

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can meet your requirement.

When multiple pipelines runs are triggered, they are added to a queue/agent and processed in the order they were received. When job in pipeline run A complete, job in pipeline run B or C could start due to the order received.

Refer to this doc: [Specify queuing policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-queuing-policies)

> YAML pipelines don't support queuing policies. Each run of a pipeline is independent from and unaware of other runs. In other words, your two successive commits may trigger two pipelines, and both of them will execute the same sequence of stages without waiting for each other

For workarounds, if you need to keep using Multi-stages, you can add the **Approvals and checks** in the **Agent Pool -> Approvals and checks**.

In this case, when you run the pipeline, you need to manually approve the Pipeline, then it can run. Or it will wait for the approval.

If you can change the multi-stages to multi-jobs, you can use the [exclusive lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-190-update#support-for-sequential-deployments-rather-than-latest-only-when-using-exclusive-lock-checks) to let the pipeline runs run in queue.

Refer to the steps:

Step1: Add exclusive lock in **Agent Pool -> Approvals and checks**.

[image]

Step2: Use multi-jobs in Pipeline and set `lockBehavior: sequential`

For example:

```
pool:
  name: default
lockBehavior: sequential
stages:
- stage:
  jobs:
  - job: test1
    steps: 
    - script:  echo "1"

  - job: test2
    steps: 
    - script:  echo "1"


  - job: test3
    steps: 
    - script:  echo "1"
```

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.